# The php script cannot return the normal character from database using mysqli_query

Tags: php

I am trying to run a php script using the php command line in linux. I run the command

php 2.php.

It can read the database, however it display strange chacracter . The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chaatz");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL';
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM smsgateway_r_users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['number'] . " " . $row['dlrDate'] . "\n";

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

It should return something like : 87654321245   1404151425

However it returns like:

```
ff483159-6eab-4f3e-97eb-a1c3d077a4d2 9911300000
ff90db23-3a3f-4885-8b11-0c68f4eef3e5 1402151333
ffa0adbe-a78b-4941-bccb-78449b82ecab 9911300000
ffd355b5-f065-4e9b-8a0b-b9d850b1cdb5 9911300000
```

Anything that I missed in the script that makes it cannot display the result properly.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the Insert statement?

Comment: Do you mean it's showing data something different than the table ? Can you run the same query in phpmyadmin & see what you get ?